Wildcarding OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_8u292b10.msi in REGEX
I need assistance with wilcarding OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_8u292b10.msi in REGEX
my expression gets me to OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_ and then fails
I've tried:

(^openjdk8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_.*\.msi$)

(openjdk8u-[ a*zA*Z0*9\\.]+msi)



Could you add information about how you test it? It seems at least the first option should be working

I've tried with https://regex101.com    and https://regexr.com/

https://regex101.com/r/7gziwL/1   see, still not working for me

this didnt work either https://regex101.com/r/p44nxC/1

aw I got it, I was missing a flag. Thanks for the help!

What regex engine?

Your first regular expression seems to be correct, as long as you set case ignore flag i, or match the beginning wist case sensitivity: ^OpenJDK8U.
In your second expression, there are a few adjustments are needed. To specify the alphabet in [] with a range, you should use - instead of *, like [a-z0-9], the * in this context represents the asterisk symbol. It also missing an _, and you do not need to special characters with \:
/openjdk8u-[a-z0-9_.]+msi

And, like in the first case, you should either specify the i flag, to ignore the case, or adjust it to match exactly.
